# font-weight not working inside @font-face

Tags: css, fonts, nuxt.js

I have a css file where I am importing some fonts now the font itself does work just fine when i use it in an element , but when i declare a font-weight property in the **@font-face** tag that does not apply.

**fonts.css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Password";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("~assets/fonts/password.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("~assets/fonts/password.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "TT Hoves Bold";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("~assets/fonts/tt_hoves_bold-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("~assets/fonts/tt_hoves_bold-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "TT Hoves Demi Bold";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url("~assets/fonts/tt_hoves_demibold-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("~assets/fonts/tt_hoves_demibold-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "TT Hoves Medium";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url("~assets/fonts/tt_hoves_medium-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("~assets/fonts/tt_hoves_medium-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  src: url("~assets/fonts/tt_hoves_regular-webfont.woff");
  font-family: "TT Hoves Regular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

**HTML**

```
h2.text{
    font-family: TT Hoves Regular
    font-size: 1.125rem
}
```

the font family does apply to this element but not the font-weight, it does work when i declare font-weight in the element but that becomes repetitive and ugly doest anyone knows how to declare and use font-weight from @font-face property?

Comment: Did you try to write font-weight after src?

Comment: I did same result

Comment: In element using `font-weight: normal`?

Comment: the element doesnot have a font-weight property by default i checked the styles tab

Comment: I think it's cause of font file. try to use another type or another source;

Comment: Why are you including weight labels ("Bold", etc.) in the font-family properties? Why not have `font-family: "TT Hoves"` in each @font-face rule and then include a font-weight property in the style declarations?

Comment: `font-face` is used to declare `style` `weight`  `name` ,It is not used to actually make font bold or so..
Thus, you will have to add multiple version of font files w.r.t weights. If font file is regular then adding font weight is not going to help.

Comment: @PeterConstable i was thinking about that myself but the font src i got from majority of the sites had separate files like this. Furthermore, the font was not available on google fonts which i normally prefer to use